# R - Degree calculation based module conditions

Tags: r, module, degrees

I have a dataframe where would like to calculate the
*degree of a country (node) - degree of its module / standard deviation of its module.*

I have calculated degree and sd of modules by

```
dgclust <- aggregate(clust[, 2], list(clust$modularity_class), mean)
sdclust <- aggregate(clust[, 2], list(clust$modularity_class), sd)
```

But I'm not sure how I can write the calculation above so that the code links `dgclust`  and `sdclust`  to the specific module the country belongs to? My expected output is a value for each country based on the described calculation. Any help appreciated!

Reproducible example

```
clust <- dput(head(clust[1:10, c(1, 5,6)]))
structure(list(Label = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Afghanistan", 
"Albania", "Algeria", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", 
"Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahrain", 
"Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", 
"Bhutan", "Bolivia (Plurinational State of)", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
"Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", 
"Burundi", "C?te d'Ivoire", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", 
"Central African Republic", "Chile", "China", "China, Hong Kong SAR", 
"China, Macao SAR", "China, Taiwan Province of", "Colombia", 
"Congo", "Costa Rica", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czechia", 
"Democratic People's Republic of Korea", "Democratic Republic of the Congo", 
"Denmark", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", 
"Eritrea", "Estonia", "Eswatini", "Ethiopia", "Finland", "France", 
"Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Greece", "Grenada", 
"Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", 
"Hungary", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran (Islamic Republic of)", 
"Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", 
"Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Lao People's Democratic Republic", 
"Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Lithuania", 
"Luxembourg", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Mali", "Malta", 
"Mauritania", "Mexico", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Morocco", 
"Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", 
"Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "North Macedonia", "Norway", 
"Oman", "Pakistan", "Palestine", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", 
"Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Qatar", 
"Republic of Korea", "Republic of Moldova", "Romania", "Russian Federation", 
"Rwanda", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", 
"Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", 
"Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Somalia", "South Africa", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", 
"Sudan", "Suriname", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic", 
"Tajikistan", "Thailand", "Timor-Leste", "Trinidad and Tobago", 
"Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", 
"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", "United Republic of Tanzania", 
"United States of America", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)", 
"Viet Nam", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), class = "factor"), 
    Degree = c(5L, 14L, 14L, 8L, 1L, 119L), modularity_class = c(3L, 
    4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L)), row.names = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", 
"Algeria", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I just created them really to use for the calculation. So (each node's degree - its module degree)/its modules sd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R, we can use `ave` to calculate `(Degree - mean)/sd` for each `modularity_class`.

```
clust <- transform(clust, result = ave(Degree, modularity_class, 
          FUN = function(x) (x - mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))/sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

This can be written in `dplyr` and `data.table` as well -

```
library(dplyr)

clust <- clust %>%
  group_by(modularity_class) %>%
  mutate(result = (Degree - mean(Degree, na.rm = TRUE))/sd(Degree, na.rm = TRUE))


library(data.table)
setDT(clust)[, result := (Degree - mean(Degree, na.rm = TRUE))/sd(Degree, na.rm = TRUE), modularity_class]
```

Comment: I see, this is a step on the way but I'm still not sure how I divide each countries' degree by its module's mean and sd? My expected output is a value for each country based on the described calculation.

Comment: Do you want to create two new columns in the data? One is degree - mean degree and another one with degree - sd degree ? Do you have only 1 row for each country?

Comment: No, I would like to have a dataframe with all countries (yes, 1 row for each country) and their respective output from calculating (node degree-mean degree of node module)/sd degree of node module.

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much -this worked perfectly!

Comment: Very sorry - I realised now the first degree of the calculation should the number of links of node i to other nodes in its module. I also have a graph object g. Is there a way to do the same operation with the within-module degree? If so, I can update my question accordingly.

Comment: For graph objects I think it would need a different approach. Can you ask that as a new question?